# How to find matched words from strings, and the percentage value?

Tags: java, android, string, percentage, string-matching

I have main string.

> String main = "hi how are you? i am fine.";

and then few strings..

> String string1 = "**hi** people what is the need................ **how** to
>   ................... do the needful..................................
>   and **you** can only need the
>   change......................................... in the **fine**
>   situation................................................. to do the
>   task................... **i am** alright............... **are you** okay?";

(may be around 100 words)

> String string2 = "**how** to do...................**i** don't know the
>   need......... what **i am** supposed to do......................**fine
>   i am**.......... okay..";

(may be around 100 words)

> String string3 = "some string again................";

(may be around 100 words)

> String string4 = "some string again................";

(may be around 100 words)

Now, what I have to do is, there are **7 words** in **main** string..

and as you can see, all those 7 words are present in string1.. 4 words are present in string2.. and continue..

So, now the percentage value for string1 is, 100%..
for string2 the percentage value is, 57.xx%.. and so on..

So, I want to get those percentage value programmatically..

What I have tried so far is,

```
String perc;

String[] q1 = str1.split(" ");
String[] q2 = main.split(" ");

for (String temp1: q1) {
    for (String temp2: q2) {
        if(temp1.equals(temp2)) {
            // Some code here
        }
    }
}
```

Now I don't know where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how it could be done:

```
String main = "hi how are you? i am fine.";
// Extract all the words whose length is > 1 and remove duplicates
Set<String> mainWords = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : main.split("\\W")) {
    if (s.length() > 1) {
        mainWords.add(s);
    }
}
String string1 = "hi people what is the need................ how to ................... do the needful.................................. and you can only need the change......................................... in the fine situation................................................. to do the task................... i am alright............... are you okay?";

Set<String> mainWordsToFind = new HashSet<>(mainWords);
// Iterate over all the words and remove the word from the list to find
for (String word : string1.split("\\W")) {
    if (word.length() > 1) {
        mainWordsToFind.remove(word);
    }
}

// Print the percent of word found
System.out.println((double) (mainWords.size() - mainWordsToFind.size()) / mainWords.size());
```

**Output:**

```
1.0
```

Comment: No i am using java 7.80

Comment: This is working.. But I have one question and that is, as there are 7 words in main string and all those words are present in string1, then % value should be 100%.. but I get **0.025157232704402517** even I did **((double) totalFound / totalWords)*100** but then value will be **2.5157232704402517** so I think this is not desirable output, otherwise your code is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Done. thank you. +1 for your continuous hard work and response.. :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String string1 = "hi people what is the need how to  do the needful and you can only need the changein the fine situation to do the task i am alright are you okay?";


    String string2 = "how to do i don't know the need what i am supposed to do fine i am okay..";

    int count = 0;
    String[] array = string1.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> processedWords = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : array){

        if (string2.contains(str) && !processedWords.contains(str) && str.length() > 0){
                System.out.println(str);

            processedWords.add(str);
            count++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Total words: " +array.length);
    System.out.println("Count: " +count);

    System.out.println("Percent value: " +((float)count/array.length)*100);
```

Comment: I get same answer for all the strings.. like same ans for str1, str2, str3, ......, strN, etc. Because I had compare all the strings with the string main..